# Minimizing estate tax on US assets of non-resident alien

Tags: united-states, non-resident, estate-planning

There is an estate tax of 40% on US situs assets of non-resident aliens. Is there any way to minimize this tax using, for example, trusts? Can someone elaborate on this?

Comment: @base64 I wanted information on trusts as a possible option..Do you know anything about that? I know you have suggested forming a company.

Comment: Company fees are fixed for each company, e.g. USD$1,000 per year. Trustee Fees are by percentage, e.g. 1% per year and your money is restricted. Nonetheless you are creating duplicate questions.

Comment: @base64 In that case, go ahead and close this question. I will edit the other one.